# I am unable to enter data using send keys

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am unable to enter data in a required field of format __-_______ (it is a 9 digit number) and not getting any errors on console.Cursor entered into the field and moved from starting to end of the field but data not entered. 
I have tried below code formats...

`driver.findElement(By.id("vendoridentificationnumber")).sendKeys("12-3456789");`

--- not working.

`driver.findElement(By.id("vendoridentificationnumber")).sendKeys("123456789");`

--- not working.

`driver.findElement(By.id("vendoridentificationnumber")).sendKeys(s.getCell(3,1).getContents());`

--- not working.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Please add the relevant html page source to the question...

Comment: Is it a single field in HTML or two text fields?

Comment: Add some html from page source. It seems the field might have some masking to support particular format of data.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, without inspecting the element where you want to insert the number simply you can inspect just before element and using Keys class you can jump to your text field and enter your data. Below is a sample line of code

```
d.findElement(By.xpath("")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB,"enter your value");
```

Hope it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to enter the value in the textbox.
Eg :
$('#textboxid').val('test')